# ArcGIS in PhoneGap

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-mobile, phonegap, windows-phone

I am trying to set up a PhoneGap application with an ArcGIS Map using a Windows Phone template in Visual Studio 2012.

I have tried using an example from the ArcGIS Javascript API samples to incorporate a Mobile ArcGIS.com map in my application:

http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/jssamples/mobile_arcgis.html

This has not worked.  I am getting the following error in Visual Studio when I try to link to the external CSS files:

> Unable to edit
>   'http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/3.4/js/esri/css/esri.css'.
>   The style sheet must be part of the current project and the project
>   must be a Web Site or Web Application project.

I found a similar example of setting up a PhoneGap project for Android with an ArcGIS Map, but this has also not worked for me.

Does anyone know of a working sample PhoneGap project to incorporate a map, using the ArcGIS Javascript API?  Alternatively, does anyone know how I can get around the error with linking the stylesheet?

Comment: You could download the API(http://www.esri.com/apps/products/download/index.cfm?fuseaction=download.all#ArcGIS_API_for_JavaScript) and host it yourself?

Comment: We had the Android version running, http://esrimobile.blogspot.com/2012/09/here-is-my-first-test-with-adobe.html no windows phones here to test/debug

Comment: If it's showing that error for the html, the link may be correct for your app, but it is different from the path that Visual Studio e.g. your using a absolute path /app/css/my.css versus relative css/my.css If that's the case, you can ignore.